# Restoring an in app purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, storekit

When an in app purchase is restored, the following delegate method is called:

```
-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

    NSLog(@"%@", queue.transactions);

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {

        //restore

    }

}
```

There are a lot of transactions in `queue.transactions` while only one product was restored (in this example there were over twenty transactions written to the log). Why? **Shouldn't there be just one transaction**? Were I to start downloading the product from my server, it would be doing twenty downloads since there are too many transactions in the array!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to process the transaction in the `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` method. The `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` is there to tell you that it is done.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                // process purchase
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                // process error
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                // process restored IAP
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this is the proper way of doing it? I found that `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions` was called as soon as the user hit the restore button, before they actually signed in and verified that they bought something. The other method (`paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`) is called after they have signed in and it still contains a list of the products to be restored.

Comment: Are you checking the transaction state of each transaction?

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, I messed up on something. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Anything placed under `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` is called when the restore has been verified by Apple. Why does `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` exist then?

Comment: It exists to let you know when all the restorations are complete. This gives you a chance to update your UI if needed.